# Add number to fopen link if that file name already exists

Tags: php, fopen, file-exists

Basically, I want to continue adding numbers each time the file already existed. So if `$url.php` exists, make it `$url-1.php`.  If `$url-1.php` exists, then make it `$url-2.php`, and so forth.

This is what I already came up with, but I think it'll only work the first time.

```
if(file_exists($url.php)) {
    $fh = fopen("$url-1.php", "a");
    fwrite($fh, $text);
} else {
    $fh = fopen("$url.php", "a");
    fwrite($fh, $text);
}
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `while` loops for scenarios like this.

```
$filename=$url;//Presuming '$url' doesn't have php extension already
$fn=$filename.'.php';
$i=1;
while(file_exists($fn)){
   $fn=$filename.'-'.$i.'.php';
   $i++;
}
$fh=fopen($fn,'a');
fwrite($fh,$text);
fclose($fh);
```

All that said, this direction of solutions does not scale well. You do not want to be checking  over a 100 `file_exists` routinely.

Comment: Simple, easy to understand code :)  Just change the cflose typo to fclose

Answer (score 2):

Use a while loop with a counter variable `$i`.  Keep incrementing the counter until `file_exists()` returns false.  At that point, the while loop exits and you call `fopen()` on the filename with the current value for `$i`;

```
if(file_exists("$url.php")) {
  $fh = fopen("$url-1.php", "a");
  fwrite($fh, $text);
} else {
  $i = 1;
  // Loop while checking file_exists() with the current value of $i
  while (file_exists("$url-$i.php")) {
    $i++;
  }

  // Now you have a value for `$i` which doesn't yet exist
  $fh = fopen("$url-$i.php", "a");
  fwrite($fh, $text);
}
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

i was looking for something similar like this and extended Shad's answer for my needs. i need to make sure that a fileupload doesn't overwrite files which already exist on a server.
i know it's not "save" yet, cause it doesn't handle files without extension. but maybe it is a little help for somebody.

```
        $original_filename = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
        if(file_exists($output_dir.$original_filename))
        {

            $filename_only = substr($original_filename, 0, strrpos($original_filename, "."));
            $ext = substr($original_filename, strrpos($original_filename, "."));

            $fn = $filename_only.$ext;
            $i=1;
            while(file_exists($output_dir.$fn)){
               $fn=$filename_only.'_'.$i.$ext;
               $i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $fn = $original_filename;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$base_name = 'blah-';
$extension = '.php';
while ($counter < 1000 ) {
    $filename = $base_name . $counter++ . $extension; 
    if ( file_exists($filename) ) continue;
}
$fh = fopen($filename, "a");
fwrite($fh, $text);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: `if(file_exists(..)) continue;` That has no meaning inside of the while loop. The default behavior is to continue...